# RegEx: Omit first single zero in flight numbers

Tags: regex, ios-shortcut

I need a RegEx to format flight numbers to keep the letter code and the following digits, but omit the leading zero if it stands alone and the total number of digits is at least four. This is used in ***iOS Shortcuts*** which is a simplified workflow with actions. I can use a match action with RegEx. Examples of desired outputs:

SK0498 should return SK498 (total digits = 4 = **omit the single leading zero**)

AA007 should still return AA007 (because the leading zeros are double, and total digits is only 3)

UA2138 returns UA2138 (no leading zeros involved)

BA023 should return BA023 (**keep the zero because total number of digits is only 3**), however
BA**0234** should return BA234 (total digits is 4 with a single leading zero that should be omitted).

I’m not good with RedEx but so far I’ve figured out `(?=0*)(00)*([1-9][\d]*)`. This correctly omits the first zero as long as it’s not double but I’m only half way there. I also want it to return the letter code, as well as honoring the minimum 4 digit rule for the leading zero to be omitted. (If the string has 4 digits with a single leading zero, omit the first, otherwise keep it). If this is even possible with this many criteria, how does it need to look?

Comment: What should happen to `AA0007`?

Comment: Hmm, I’d say omit the first zero so it becomes AA007.

Comment: The solution could be simplified then - replace `(?=[1-9]\d{2}\b)` with `(?=\d{3}\b)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to omit the first single zero, you could use a capture group for the leading uppercase chars and use that group in the replacement:

```
\b([A-Z]+)0(?=[1-9]\d{2}\b)
```

The pattern matches:

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match
- `([A-Z]+)` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ chars A-Z
- `0` Match the zero (if you want to match 1 or more zeroes, then `0+`)
- `(?=[1-9]\d{2}\b)` Positive lookahead, assert a digit 1-9 followed by 2 digits and a word boundary (4 consecutive digits in total)

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UlYDEY/1)

If there is a minimum 4 digit rule, you can omit the last word boundary, and assert at least 2 digits:

```
\b([A-Z]+)0(?=[1-9]\d{2})
```

---

If there can be 3 digits to the right with a leading zero, and you want to remove the first zero only:

```
\b([A-Z]+)0(?=\d{3}\b)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XRyQ5Z/1)

Comment: Ah there we are! Clever to use the zero in a capture group for the chars. I was too focused on trying to find a solution with chars in one group and digits in another. Thanks!

Comment: I was a bit quick here. It’s still a correct solution but the problem I didn’t realize first is I don’t have the $1 replace in iOS Shorcuts. It’s just a simple match with regex action so I need the output to directly become the answer, ie just omit the 0, keep the rest.

Comment: @ScoobyDooku If a lookbehind assertion is supported `(?<=[A-Z])0(?=[1-9]\d{2}\b)` https://regex101.com/r/f3SmTx/1

Comment: @ScoobyDooku Or if there are always 2 uppercase chars to the left `(?<=\b[A-Z][A-Z])0(?=\d{3}\b)` https://regex101.com/r/HDpRet/1

Comment: That seems to return the 0 I don’t want, if it is present, and ignores everything else. In other words the complete opposite. With that code, SK0498 becomes 0, I need the output to become SK498.

Comment: @ScoobyDooku You can not skip characters in a single match. Perhaps like this `\b[A-Z][A-Z](?=0\d{3}\b)|(?<=\b[A-Z][A-Z]0)\d{3}\b` https://regex101.com/r/laTdlk/1

Comment: I suspected that. I got it to work via a combination. First break out the two letters, then the digits. Once formatted (0 omitted) I combined the two back and put it in a variable for later use. Thanks for your inputs

Answer (score 1):

You can also try to find letters, and the last three numbers then concatenate them together as follows:

```
import re

for s in ['BA023', 'BA0432', 'BA0007']:
  numbers = re.findall('\d+', s)[0][-3:]
  alpha = re.findall('[a-zA-Z]+', s)[0]
  print(alpha+numbers, s)
```